# Limiting URL request in xcode

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

Is there a way to make a URL request link user specific? I am trying to make certain links to my Firebase storage files user specific. Will I have to change the code in xcode or in the Firebase storage rules?

```
func yhandleDownload() {
    print(123)
    let webView = UIWebView (frame: view.frame)
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com")!))

    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

This is how my code is set up right now, which allows all users logged into the application to open the link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built in download methods (for instance, here we're going to use FirebaseUI to download an image straight into a `UIImageView`):

```
// Get the current user's UID
let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth().currentUser?.uid

// Reference to a user's image file in Firebase Storage
let reference = storageRef.child("users/\(currentUser)/image.png")

// UIImageView in your ViewController
let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

// Placeholder image
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

// Load the image using SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

As well as set your security rules appropriately:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{userId}/{allUserFiles=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Per [the security rules docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security)